# recusively group and count/max records for a given datetime interval

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I had another question opened, but this one is hopefully more clear and targeted at what I'm needing assistence with.

Sample data: (SQL Fiddle link included below)

```
groupid     custid      cust_type   cust_date           data_total_1    data_total_2
CA123       ABC12345    SLE         January, 01 2014    5               10
CA123       ABC12345    SLE         February, 01 2014   2               5
CA123       ABC12345    SLE         March, 01 2014      7               11
CA123       ABC12345    SLE         April, 01 2014      7               4
FL444       BBB22222    SLE         January, 01 2014    2               3
FL444       BBB22222    SLE         March, 01 2014      7               21
FL444       BBB22222    SLE         July, 01 2014       3               9
WA999       ZZZ99909    NSLE        April, 01 2014      2               10
WA999       ZZZ99909    NSLE        May, 01 2014        4               9
```

For each given groupid, custid, cust_type combination, I need to grab evaluate records within a given time interval (3 months).  I need to count the number of records and grab the max data_total_x values that exist within the "range" for each record.

My expected output looks similar to this:

```
groupid     custid      cust_type   cust_date           custid_count    max_data_total_1    max_data_total_2
CA123       ABC12345    SLE         January, 01 2014    4               7                   11
CA123       ABC12345    SLE         February, 01 2014   3               7                   11
CA123       ABC12345    SLE         March, 01 2014      2               7                   11
CA123       ABC12345    SLE         April, 01 2014      1               7                   4
FL444       BBB22222    SLE         January, 01 2014    2               7                   21
FL444       BBB22222    SLE         March, 01 2014      1               7                   21
FL444       BBB22222    SLE         July, 01 2014       1               3                   9
WA999       ZZZ99909    NSLE        April, 01 2014      2               4                   10
WA999       ZZZ99909    NSLE        May, 01 2014        1               4                   9
```

SQL Fiddle that includes sample data and my attempt at it: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba5a53/10/0

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
select
  groupid,
  custid,
  cust_type,
  f.custid_count,
  f.max_data_total_1,
  f.max_data_total_2
from records r
outer apply (
  select 
    count(*) as custid_count,
    max(data_total_1) as max_data_total_1,
    max(data_total_2) as max_data_total_2
  from
    records r2
  where
    r.groupid = r2.groupid and
    r.custid = r2.custid and
    r.cust_type = r2.cust_type and
    r2.cust_date <= dateadd(month, 3, r.cust_date) and
    r2.cust_date >= r.cust_date
) f
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba5a53/14

Comment: This does indeed work.  It may not be the most optimal in terms of speed at least with the few million rows I'm evaluating it against, but it does work.  I almost wonder if storing the results in a temporary table rather than using outer apply would be faster?

Comment: I would assume it being quite heavy for millions of rows. Having covered index should help so that key lookups aren't needed. Not sure if temp. table will help since you'll have to do the fetches for each row anyhow, but that way you could do it in smaller parts, which could help at least a little.